# Get image from cellForRowAtIndexPath to didSelectRowAtIndexPath to push when row is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to push the image from selected row to a detailed viewController. This is what I tried the latest. I also tried to get the PFFile from an PFImageView but unsuccessful.

```
 #import "ExploreViewController.h"
 #import "DetailExploreViewController.h"

 @interface ExploreViewController ()

 @property (strong, nonatomic) PFGeoPoint *userLocation;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIImage *imagine; 
 @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *discovery;

 @end


    - (PFQuery *) queryForTable
{
    if (!self.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HomePopulation"];
    [query whereKey:@"geopoint" nearGeoPoint:self.userLocation withinKilometers:15];
    query.limit = 25;

    //[self getLocation];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"ExploreCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"discovery"];


    PFFile *getImage = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    [getImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            NSLog(@"hojla: %@", cell.imageView.image);
        } else {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1bar.jpg"];
        }
    }];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewer didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableViewer cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.discovery = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"the text: %@", self.discovery);

    self.imagine = cell.imageView.image;

    NSLog(@"ajde: %@", self.imagine);

}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
        DetailExploreViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.theImage = self.imagine;
        destViewController.theString = self.discovery;
    }
}
```

DetailExploreViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailExploreViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *theString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *theImage;

@end
```

DetailExploreViewController.m

```
#import "DetailExploreViewController.h"

@interface DetailExploreViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel;

@end

@implementation DetailExploreViewController

@synthesize theString, theLabel, theImageView, theImage;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    theLabel.text = theString;
    theImageView.image = theImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paulw11's advice I made it happen like this:

ExploreViewController.m

```
- (PFQuery *) queryForTable {
    if (!self.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }     
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HomePopulation"];
    [query whereKey:@"geopoint" nearGeoPoint:self.userLocation withinKilometers:15];

    query.limit = 25;

    // Calling getData to populate the array at the same time as the tableView is being loaded
    [self getData];
    return query;

}

//Retrieving objects from Parse and adding them in a NSMutableArray
- (void)getData { 
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HomePopulation"];
    [query whereKey:@"geopoint" nearGeoPoint:self.userLocation withinKilometers:15];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                Detailish *detail = [Detailish new]; // Detailish is a class for the array objects
                detail.discovery = [object objectForKey:@"discovery"];
                PFFile *getImage = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
                [getImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        detail.imagine = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        NSLog(@"Detail imagine: %@", detail.imagine);
                    }
                }];
                detail.location = [object objectForKey:@"location"];

                [forDetail addObject:detail];
            }
        }
    }];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject
*)object {
    static NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"ExploreCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"discovery"];


    return cell; }


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
        DetailExploreViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSLog(@"Halo ej: %@", [forDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        destViewController.hump = [forDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

        Detailish *details = [forDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"discovery: %@", details.discovery);
        NSLog(@"image: %@", details.imagine);
    } }

DetailExploreViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Detailish.h"

@interface DetailExploreViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Detailish *hump;

@end

DetailExploreViewController.m
#import "DetailExploreViewController.h"

@interface DetailExploreViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel;

@end

@implementation DetailExploreViewController

@synthesize theLabel, theImageView;


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    theLabel.text = self.hump.discovery;
    theImageView.image = self.hump.imagine;
}

Detailish.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Detailish : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *discovery;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *location;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *imagine;

@end

Detailish.m
#import "Detailish.h"

@implementation Detailish

@synthesize discovery, location, imagine;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are creating a new `UIImageView` to contain your image, but not doing anything with it.  Once you have the image you can just assign it to the cell's `imageView.image` property -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
    {
        static NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"ExploreCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"discovery"];

        PFFile *getImage = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
        [getImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                NSLog(@"hojla: %@", cell.imageView.image);
            }
            else {
               //TODO - Put some placeholder/"not found" image into cell.imageView.image
            }
        }];

        return cell;
    }
```

Then, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewer didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewer cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = cell.textLabel
    NSLog(@"the text: %@", label.text);

    UIImageView *img = cell.imageView;

    NSLog(@"ajde: %@", img.image);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid respond. Unfortunately this just sets the image to the cell on whichever cell I tap. I need to get the image from this cell.imageView so that I can push it to my DetailViewController where I show it.

Comment: Are you asking how you can send the retrieved image to your detailViewController?

Comment: How is your detail view presented?  Are you pushing it in a navigation controller?  Using a storyboard/segue?

Comment: It looks ok. All you are missing is the [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail"]; in didSelectCellArIndexPath. Also it is probably better to access the properties in viewWillAppear than in viewDidLoad

Comment: Also I updated my answer - in didSelectCellaforIndexPath you can use the passed tableview in the call to cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: If I do [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail"];, then I get "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted." Because I already have push in storyboard. My image doesn't even come to didSelectRowAtIndexPath (when I log it, it's (null).

Comment: I think that may be because you are loading the image in the background. Unless you have hundreds of images it is better to load them outside of your cellForRowAtIndexPath and then just assign it from an array in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I'll try that, but I don't see why it would work any better since the tableeview is populated nicely direct from Parse.

Comment: You have a potential race condition between the background task/completion handler that populates the image & text and the prepareForSegue invocation

Comment: Solved! I went with assigning objects in the array. Check out the solution in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a message to the detail controller instead of using the dot syntax like so:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
        DetailExploreViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [destViewController setTheImage:self.theImage];
        [destViewController setTheString:self.theString];
    }
}
```

In the detail controller implementation file , I would set up the detail view image in the `viewWillAppear` method instead like so:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    theLabel.text = theString;
    theImageView.image = theImage;

}
```

This works for me.